# Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 500 seconds exceeded

Tags: php, curl, fatal-error

I'm using cURL with PHP and getting the following error after sometime (I guess after 300 sec):

> Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 500 seconds exceeded.

I googled this and found some solutions that are also not working for me, such as:

```
ini_set('MAX_EXECUTION_TIME', -1);
error_reporting(1);   // to display only fatal error
set_time_limit(0);
```

I've tried both `MAX_EXECUTION_TIME` and `MAX_INPUT_TIME` and set them to `-1` but nothing is helping me.

**Update**

I've used this as well:

```
ignore_user_abort(true);
ini_set('MAX_EXECUTION_TIME', 0);
error_reporting(1);
set_time_limit(0);
```

and inside `cURL`

```
curl_setopt($s, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 0);
```

but it is still giving me the following error:

> Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 500 seconds exceeded in D:\wamp\www\optimized.php on line 321

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6509980/fatal-error-maximum-execution-time-of-30-seconds-exceeded-in-script)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set it too 300 which is approx 300 secs = 5 minutes

```
ini_set('MAX_EXECUTION_TIME', 300);
```

if you set it to 0 , which mean no limits.

```
ini_set('MAX_EXECUTION_TIME', 0);
```

for cURL you can use this one

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 0);
```

here again 0 means infinite...

Comment: what if we set it to -1?
`ini_set('MAX_EXECUTION_TIME', -1);`

Comment: OK..I'll try this too.

Comment: currently script is running and I'd put `sleep(2)` function to slow it down .. because It worked once. So if it stops again, I'll try this

Comment: Is it still showing `execution time of 500 seconds` ????  after you set is to 0???

Answer (score 0):

As you are using curl, make the curl's timeout `infinite` using `0`

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 0); // or provide number of seconds!
```

Comment: OK. but currently I'm using `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 9000);`

Comment: @Mubin You should have mentioned this in your question! Try running the code from console using `php script .php` command and check whether it runs or not, if still gets timeout then probably its the issue with your `php` configuration in `php.ini`

Comment: @Mubin look for the `max_execution_time` in your `php.ini` file as well. Though you have set this from code, but try to change from ini file as well, as its not working for you!

Comment: How to run this from command line?
I'd tried to add php.exe path in my computer's properties and try to run this 
`c:/path_to_php.exe -f path_toFile`

Answer (score 0):

I change :

> default_socket_timeout=1200

on **php.ini**

It worked for me.